# Forgot to feed my 6-day old sourdough starter yesterday, can I just carry on today?

Tags: sourdough, starter

I just realized that yesterday I forgot to feed my 6-day old sourdough starter, can I just go about feeding it as usual? I know there are some similar questions on here but they are a little vague. I want to be specific that it's a brand new starter and I've never done this before. I've been feeding it consistently for the other days but had some things come up yesterday that made me forget.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if I forget to feed my sourdough starter?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/100403/what-happens-if-i-forget-to-feed-my-sourdough-starter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carry on!  If you find that you are going to go a while between bakes, store it in the fridge and feed weekly.  [The Perfect Loaf](https://www.theperfectloaf.com/7-easy-steps-making-incredible-sourdough-starter-scratch/) has a nice primer on starters.